# JasperReports: default value instead of 'null'

Tags: jasper-reports

Is there any way to set a default value to a field in a report? I have a lot of String fields in a report and would like them to display "0,00" when they're null.

Comment: if you are not satisfied with the answers please add more details to your question

Comment: I think that You should also change the text value to numeric value and set pattern and then eventualy set 0 not the "0,00" because it is not global formating for numbers.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Supposing the field name is "value", in the "Text Field Expression", write:

`($F{value} != null) ? $F{value} : "0.00"`

Comment: Make sure to check the scripting language setting for the report, for me in iReport Designer 4.0.2 this syntax works in Java but not in Groovy

Answer (score 5):

You can also select "Blank when null" in the properties of the text field if you want that. Other options are more flexible but this does the trick very quick and easy.

Comment: Much more elegant and simple solution than the previous ones.

Comment: Yeah but it only works if you just have the single field in the text box.

Answer (score 4):

medopal's answer is good, but 2 additions:

1) You can make the syntax shorter:

`($F{field_name}) ? $F{field_name} : "0.00"`

2) Make sure your "else" data is of the same class as the field's value, otherwise you'll get errors when it tries to coerce numbers into string, etc. etc. This was something that, as I started out, I mixed up.

Comment: When I remove the ` != null` I get `Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to boolean`.

Comment: It's very possible the tech has changed in the 7 years since I provided this answer, at the time I tested that it worked before posting. I'm no longer an active user of JasperReports, @JamieKitson I hope you find an up-to-date resource that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try set a pattern in the text field?

If you are using iReport this can be found in the properties for the text field in the `Text Field Properties` section.

Try something along the lines of `###0.00` to represent 1234.56, which would always display 0.00 even if it is null.

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way is to use `Coalesce() or NVL()` function of database in your data-source query to restrict null data on your report.

But it depends on if you are allowed to change the datasource query or not. If not then you can go for other solutions provided in previous answers.