# How do I replace a null value with 0?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a report, with the fields A and B coming from my database. In the select statement sometime A and B are null.

Problem is when I ask for the group sum of A - B and one of the record has a null in it the total for the sum is null.

How do I get around this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JasperReports: default value instead of 'null'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402237/jasperreports-default-value-instead-of-null)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In jasper-reports variable expression you can use [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Java)

```
($F{value1}!=null?$F{value1}:0)
```

which means if `value1` is different from `null` then use `value1` otherwise use `0`

**jrxml variable declaration example**

```
<variable name="varWithTernary" class="java.lang.Double" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[($F{value1}!=null?$F{value1}:0)-($F{value2}!=null?$F{value2}:0)]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

With these kind of statements your are able to handle `null` value as you like