# Replace null value in Text Field Expression

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a field in my *JasperReports*'s report which has a expression value like `$F{openstock}+$F{production}+$F{mrq}` All this fields are double.

I have totaled the sum into a variable `opm`. Sometimes the value of `openstock` is null sometimes the value of `mrq` is null so `opm` is not showing anything. How could I ignore the null values or replace `null` to `0.00`

Comment: What type of a datasource?

Comment: I used database source to get the data ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JasperReports: default value instead of 'null'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402237/jasperreports-default-value-instead-of-null)