# How to print 0 when count is null from sql in Jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

I am displaying count returned from a SQL query on a jasper report.

If the count is `null`, it is leaving the text box empty; how can I print 0 instead? The field name is `countoccurence`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JasperReports: default value instead of 'null'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402237/jasperreports-default-value-instead-of-null)

Comment: You are right. It is almost a duplicate. I was not able to to find it sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone might be helped. I was able to resolve by putting below in the expression (under text field properties)
     $F{yourfieldname}!=null?$F{yourfieldname}:0